# Owl Carousel - jumping to a specific slide

Tags: owl-carousel

We have an About page that contains 5 video reels within the Owl carousel: http://24fpsproductions.com/24fps/about.html (Television, Commercial, Digital, Food, and Corporate)

We want to be able to link people to specific slides both from within the site and externally. For example, we would add a submenu under the "About" menu to include direct links to all 5 reels. So if someone was on our site, and selected About>Reels>Digital, the About page would open, and the Carousel would queue up to the Digital reel. Or, we could send an e-mail with a link that goes directly to the About page, queuing up the Food reel.

This seems to be possible, though I don't see a solution here on the forum. There are related posts, but nothing that tackles this specific challenge.

Lastly, we have other carousels on our site, so I would want the solution to apply only to this carousel.

I'm hoping someone can help.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you. Stack Overflow is a programming site, including sample code is typically a minimum requirement. :)

Comment: Thanks, Marc. I don't have any code to post, as I'm actual;y looking for code.